# OpenCover: Specify in an external file what assemblies should be ignored

Tags: c#, jenkins, opencover

We are putting in place some code analysis with openCover. I would like to know if it is possible to specify a file with the files to exclude from the cover?

Typically, we have some external project that we have the code source and we want to exclude. It's the same job on jenkins that allow us to build every branch, but we may have different things to exclude depending on the branch.

Also since we have a lot of Tools/prototypes projects, we dont want to have them included.

We need different kind of exclusions:

- By file names(exclude all *.Designer.cs)
- By assembly pattern(Exclude all assembly finishing by ".Tests")
- By specific assembly name

I don't want to specify everything on the command line(most people will not be able to edit the job and this becomes really dirty).

Answer (score 0):

There is only `-filterfile` which is used for assembly/class filters